# How to display measure as sub-columns in matrix visual in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I want to display 3 measures under all the columns in a matrix visual.
[image]

Face amount, Market value are numeric columns in the table.

ConvexityWTD is a measure.

I want to calculate Prior, current and %change measures based on some condition and display them under each of the column.

I am getting the following table by keeping this arrangement:

[image]

[image]

How can I get it in the required format?

Comment: Have you looked here: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-august-2017-feature-summary/#valuesOnRows

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your table with some data in it? At first glance it seems to me you need to restrucutre your data into a column (e.g .Type) which has text values: Face Amount - Market Value - ConvexityWtd. So you need to transform the table.

Comment: I agree with Aldert. Unpivotting the Face/Market/Convexity columns will make this much easier.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I agree, unpivoting the columns would make things a lot easier. 
I have done that and now I am working with the DAX syntax for the 3 measures.
I will keep you updated on the syntax.